# Товарищи, что не так?

Tags: java

Напишите основной метод, который считывает ваш возраст с клавиатуры, а затем сообщает вам, сколько вам будет лет в 2050 году. Программа должна запрашивать возраст несколько раз, если не было введено число от 0 до 100. Предположим, что целое число всегда вводится.

```
package uebung9;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Alter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Сколько вам лет?");
        int old = scan.nextInt();
        if (old <1 & old>100);
        System.out.println("Введите правильное число");

        int year = scan.nextInt();

        int a = 2050-year;

        System.out.println(a);



    }

}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Ваш код ищет год, который был `year` лет назад, относительно 2050 года. Вам нужно считать `(2050 - *текущий год*) + year`. Например, если человеку 28 лет, то `(2050 - 2020) + 28` = 58 лет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем варианте проще перечислить, что написано правильно, чем перечислить, что написано неправильно. Единственное, что я совсем не могу понять, как вы пришли к этому int a = 2050-year; вот предположим вам 25 лет. Тогда по вашей логике в 2050 году вам будет 2025 лет. Поздравляю, вы долгожитель!

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Alter {
    
    private final static int futureYear = 2050;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Сколько вам лет?");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("В " + futureYear + " вам будет " + calculateAge(scan.nextLine(), futureYear));                
                break;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Введите правильное число");
            }
        }

    }
    
    private static int calculateAge(String yearsOld, int futureYear) {
        int intYearsOld = Integer.valueOf(yearsOld);
        if (intYearsOld < 1 || intYearsOld > 100) throw new NumberFormatException();
        return futureYear - (LocalDate.now().getYear() - intYearsOld);
    }

}
```

Comment: спасибо, а для чего нужно их приравнивать int intYearsOld = Integer.valueOf(yearsOld);

Comment: @Kamran на самом деле причин несколько.логический оператор использует логическое "или" в совокупности с магическими цифрами (1 и 100), что уже само по себе антипаттерн и сильно ухудшает читаемость кода.  если затолкать туда дважды Integer.valueOf(yearsOld), то все станет еще хуже. кроме того Integer.valueOf(yearsOld) - достаточно медленная операция, чтобы ее дублировать (ведь в аргументах стринг, а с ним число сравнить нельзя). посему корретнее вынести распарсивание числа в отдельное выражение и присвоить переменной с осмысленным именем. примерно так

Answer (score 0):

Корень зла таится здесь:

```
if (old <1 & old>100);
    System.out.println("Введите правильное число");
```

1. Одиночный `&` квалифицируется как битовый `and`, надо ставить двойной амперсанд `&&`
2. Точка с запятой после `if` квалифицируется как конец `if`

Правильный код:

```
if (old <1 && old>100)
    System.out.println("Введите правильное число");
```

**Update**

```
if (old <1 || old>100)
    System.out.println("Введите правильное число");
```

Comment: Ну как же такое - ``if (old <1 && old>100)`` - может быть правильным?

Comment: Точно :) ну надо же а )))